# Principal solutions of trigonometric equations and angle between two lines.

Tags: trigonometry, analytic-geometry

In the fig., the red line has a slope of $\frac{1}{2}$ and the green line has a slope of 3.

[image]

We can find the angle $\theta$ between the lines as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
{}&{\tan \theta}
&{}={}& {\frac{m_2~-~m_1}{1~+~m_1 m_2}}
&{} \\
{}&{}
&{}={}& {\frac{3~-~\frac{1}{2}}{1~+~\frac{1}{2}  × 3}}
&{} \\
{}&{}
&{}={}& {\frac{6 ~-~1}{2~+~3}}
&{} \\
{}&{}
&{}={}& {\frac{5}{5}}
&{} \\
{}&{}
&{}={}& {1}
&{} \\
\end{array}$

So we have to solve the equation $\tan \theta = 1$.

But there are two values that will satisfy the equation. They are: $45^o~\text{and}~225^o$.

Could you please explain how $225^o$ is related to the "angle between the two lines".
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A,B,C,D$ denote the points $(2,1.5), (4,2.5), (2.5,3),$ and $(1.5,0).$

Then, the red and green lines intersect at point $A$, point $B$ is on the red line and both of points $C$ and $D$ are on the green line.

Then, $\angle BAC = 45^\circ$ and $\angle BAD = 225^\circ,$ when traversed in a counter-clockwise direction.